# Does mainnet support Whisper protocol?

Tags: go-ethereum, whisper, shh

I am interested in Whisper. I read that Whisper is based on Ethereum p2p protocol on github. Then does ethereum mainnet support Whisper on itself too ?

Anyway, what I wonder is ...
1. Is Whisper only supported on private networks ?
2. If the purpose of someone's private network is for exchanging Whisper messages only, then what is the data in the private blockchain ?

There is no white paper for Whisper now.. Does anyone have an idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Currently most of (all of) mainnet do not support Whisper protocol.

It needs to be explicitly enabled by node operators. Not sure how reliably you can connect to it.

Here is some old information:

https://www.sitepoint.com/ethereum-messaging-whisper-status/

https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/11178/620